# Learning how to fly a 3" quad

Tags: recommendations, under-250-grams

Preface: I'm a newer pilot to the FPV world with limited stick time on 5".

I just built and flew a 3" for the first time. LOS is not a problem for verifying functionality. Then I put on the goggles and almost lost my mind! The throttle is super touchy. Seems like just a couple clicks off of minimum and it's climbing above the trees. All other controls seem reasonable.

My options as I see them:

1. Using a 3 cell battery (I'm using 4s) for a bit to get used to it.
2. Change to a lower pitch prop. Not sure what I have on there now but 4" pitch seems likely. I'll have to check when I can.
3. Throttle scaling in BetaFlight. An option but seems like training wheels, in a way. I feel like I should learn it as it is. Scaling seems like it would drag out the learning curve.
4. More stick time. Just fly it as it is and start in a big field and get the stick time.

What is the best option path? I'm guessing option 4 but I'm open to other's experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Throttle scaling is not training wheels so don't feel back about using it.  It's never fun to fly a quad with a throttle that is too touchy.

Another option is throttle expo which you can turn on in the rates area of Betaflight.  Find the hover point for the quad and set that to be the center of your throttle curve. Then add some expo to soften the rate and give you some more resolution at the hover point.

Also keep in mind that with a 3" inch size, matching your motor kV and battery cell counts are very important. If your motors are up at 6000kv area you probably want to stay with 3s batteries.

Comment: I got out to a large field and flew a few batteries today. Feels better out in the open. I think I may have expected less power than that from a 3". I think I'll try some expo on the throttle like you suggested, though.  Thanks again